# Wasm traps in ink contract but not in a `wasm-pack` test

Tags: ink, wasm, wasmi

I have a contract that implements some ZKP verification logic with `plonk`. The verification logic is contained in some other crate that can be compiled to Wasm, and there are `wasm-pack` tests like this:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen_test]
fn generate_proof_test() {
        // const DEPTH: usize = DEFAULT_DEPTH;
        let R = ...;
        let proof: [u8; 1040] = ...;
        let account = alice_account;
        let h: [u8; 32] = ...;

        verify_proof(R, proof, account, h).unwrap();
    }
```

The problem is that this test works fine with `wasm-pack test`, but when I import this very same logic into my `ink!` contract, the call fails and I get `{ Err: { Module: { index: 8 error: 0x0b000000 } } }`, which is `ContractTrapped` in `polkadot-v0.9.37` version of `pallet-contracts`.
The verification function is quite large (roughly 70kB, optimized), and it made me wonder if there can be differences between `wasm-pack` Wasm and `wasmi` Wasm in `pallet-contracts`. When I debugged the exact `Trap` reason, it turned out to be an `unreachable` instruction encountered.

So, my question is: should I try looking harder for any logical errors in my code, or can the call somehow fail with an `unreachable` instruction due to the size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within some of my dependencies. Rolling them back helped.

Comment: Which dependencies were the cause of this issue?

Comment: @Snowmead it was a ZKP library, `dusk_plonk`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is related of the size (of your contract) you can still tweak this [value](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/fe44851126245fec8bf17a39f618d7ce54d0bc76/runtime/src/lib.rs#L364) and check. But this will happen at upload time not at call time.

One great option would be to add ink! e2e tests it will be easier to debug.

Can you share which node & version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using the latest `pallet-contracts` at 0.9.37, `ink` version 4. E2E tests don't work yet because of [this](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1672) issue :)